# how to access elements defined in parent scope within a ng-included partial

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to use a common partial template for a couple of views in my application. But for some reason the partial does not load the elements defined in the parent scope (Most probably because ng-include creates a new child scope). How can I get access to the elements defined under the parent scope.

### Example:

#### *main.html*:

```
<div id="application" ng-app="myapp">
    <div id="content">
        <!-- Main Application View for Auto Updating -->
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### *some view*:

```
<!-- some html -->
<div ng-include="'/partials/common_partial.html'"></div>
```

#### *common partial.html*:

```
{{ item.name }}
{{ item.code }}
{{ item.expiry }}
```

Now I want to add common_partials.html to different view/controllers where within a controller's scope i set the element item. Say, in the above view's controller I do `$scope.item = {'name': 'Test', 'code': 'DS3F432DI', 'expiry': '30 Days'}`

Now if I directly call `{{item.name}}` in the view it renders the name but not within the partial added using `ng-include` how can i access `{{item.foo}}` in common_template.html ?

Comment: But, it does work ([plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/PkjLlPA38WOBuxJZsaCW))??

Comment: @Stewie: Oops yeah, it is working. My bad, I just realized it was working for all other elements but does not work for elements updated after rendering the template.

Comment: If variables in your expressions are referenced (through `object.property` notation) you shouldn't have problems with updates either.

Comment: Actually, It is much more complicated. My common partial sets a element in scope called `current_item` using `ng-model="current_item"` and uses `ng-change=changeFunction()` to update the fields. `changeFunction` needs the `current_item` element which within the controller is undefined and that is why on selecting a different `item` view does not update

Comment: and yes after I pass in the `current_item` as an argument within the common template and use the argument instead in the `changeFunction` it works. :)

Comment: Glad it worked. I suggest you just update your question and provide an accepted answer to move the post from the "Unanswered" list.

Comment: Have you tried to access using `$parent.item.name` from your partial template? I solved my problem in this way